# How to remove white space from masonry image gallery

Tags: jquery, html, css

You can check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rrPs8/)**

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/130" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/160/120" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/170/110" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/180/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/190/110" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/180/120" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/170/130" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/160/140" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/130" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  columnWidth: 1,
  itemSelector: '.item',
  gutter: 10
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got this working while defining `.item` as `columnWidth` in masonry js. And adding some style to `.item`

**[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k4zC4/2/)**

JS

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  columnWidth: '.item',
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

CSS

```
.item {
    width: 19.8%;
    height: auto;
    margin:0.1%;
}
.item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this: (beautiful cats :p)

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/190/110" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/130" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/180/120" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/160/120" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/170/110" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/170/130" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/180/100" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/160/140" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/130" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rrPs8/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, i dont want to rearrange the img list, i am doing this for wordpress theme and user cant rearrange the img list.

Comment: just got it working see now http://jsfiddle.net/k4zC4/2/ , anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: @VikasGhodke:- Good one!!! But you have reduced the size of the images which you dont wanted(This is what I have interpreted!!!!)

Comment: No actually i didnt want to rearrange the images as you done in your answer. Reducing the image size is acceptable.

Comment: @VikasGhodke:- Yes I got it but this is not the way how I interpreted it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's just the nature of the plugin; since your code doesn't have any items small enough to fill the space, it skips past it. If you can make the items smaller, even 90% of the current size, it'll be easier for the to fill the given space – think peas in a jar as compared to sand in a jar.

Beyond that, increasing gutter space might make that big gap look less intense, but not fix everything.

Comment: Yes you are right, i am working on this since last 2 days with isotope and masonry but still no sucess, but you can check this http://themewich.com/gridstack

Comment: just got it working see now http://jsfiddle.net/k4zC4/2/ , anyways thanks for your help.